# Loop through array at certain speed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, telemetry

I'm new here so spare me please.

I'm working on a little hobby project of mine where an application gathers telemetry which is recorded and saved at 60Hz (so 60 index in an array for each second). This is always the case.

I then want to 'play through' this array at the regular speed as if you're playing a video. But instead of seeing a video I want to show the current data from each index that you're at on the frontend.

The structure of the array is not made yet, but I assume I will just store and load a JSON file somewhere in the database. This then should be played through in my frontend. I've used Angular (6) to build that, so it would be great if it could be mixed with Angular (to keep track of the progress of which index you are now, and bind the values of the current index to the frontend).

Would it be easy to just use 0-1-2-etc for indexx, or maybe something like timestamps?

Any suggestions are welcome. The most important thing here is to keep it quick so you don't need a strong rig to play this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `setInterval` function in which you will iterate over the array according to your frequency. So if your frequency is `60hz` that means you want to iterate to next element in array after every `1000 / 60` milliseconds

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

var currentIndex = 0;

var interval = 1000 / 60

var id = setInterval(function() {
  // do your thing
  if(currentIndex == (data.length-1)) {
    clearInterval(id)
  } else {
    currentIndex++
  }
}, interval)
```

This is not a particularly iterating over array but rather doing some action after interval of time and then moving to next item and when you are done with array this will clear the interval. Perhaps linked list will be more helpful than array here

Comment: Of course! Thanks for that. Took a look at linked lists, but I'm not sure if that's gonna work for me. I also want a 'play' bar where you can skip to a moment (index). And it looks like linked lists don't exactly work like that?

Comment: It does you just need to jump to next of next instead of next ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can make yourself a simple runner for such things. It's basically a game engine and you need a game loop :)

Here's a naive example. Skipping most of error checking and validation here for brewity.

```
class TelemetryPlayer {
  constructor(items, render, interval) {
    // setup local data. 
    this.interval = interval;
    this.items = items;
    this.render = render;
    this.startLoop();
  }

  // Loop simply initializes before the first run, and then runs the loop.
  // Other places do the actual work. 
  startLoop() {
    this._renderInProgress = false;
    this._currentIndex = 0;
    // save the interval reference if you wanna pause/reset later on.
    this._interval = setInterval(this.doWork.bind(this), this.interval);    
  }

  // here we perform the actual render.
  doWork() {
    if (this._renderInProgress) {
      // previous render has not completed yet.
      console.log('skip');
      return;
    }
    console.log('Tick');
    this._renderInProgress = true;
    const item = this.items[this._currentIndex];
    console.log('Tick');

    // now, call your renderer, and update stuff when complete.
    this.render(item)
      .then(() => {
        // Or this can be a callback or similar.
        this._renderInProgress = false;
        // Ready next item. Do not go out of array bounds.
        this._currentIndex++;
        if (this._currentIndex === this.items.length) {
          this._currentIndex = 0;
        }
      });
  }

  // You can then add fun things like skip, pause, reset etc.
  skip(item)  {
    if (item < 0 || item > this.items.length) {
      return;
    }
    // pause first
    this.pause();
    this._currentIndex = item;
    this.unpause();
  }
  //
  reset() {
    this.skip(0);
  } 
  //
  pause() {
    this._interval = clearInterval(this._interval);
  }

  unpause() {
    if (!this._interval) {
      this._interval = setInterval(this.doWork.bind(this), this.interval);    
    }
  }

  // you can even add items later
  addItem(item) {
    this.items.push(item);
  }

  // or replace them.
  replaceItem(item, index) {
    this.items[index] = item;
    // show the new item right away.
    this.skip(index);
  }

  // or add an item to be played just once.
  playOnce(item) {
    this.pause();
    this.render(item);
    this.unpause();
  }
}
```

Now here's an example usage. You can copy the code (both class above and the code block bellow) and paste it into console right here on StackOverflow to see it in work. You likely wanna do other things, but you'll get the gist.

```
let items = [ 100, 200, 300, 50, 100, 200, 300, 250 ];

const timeline = document.createElement('ul');
// maybe better do this by adding class and external stylesheet
timeline.setAttribute('style', 'padding: 15px; border: 1px solid gray; list-style-type: none; height: 500px; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0;overflow-y: scroll;')
document.body.appendChild(timeline);

let render = function(item)  {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    // run something (in) expensive with item now.
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    // again, better do this with class.
    li.setAttribute('style', `display: inline-block; width: 25px; margin: 5px; background-color: #c1c1c1; height: ${item}px;`);
    timeline.appendChild(li);
    li.scrollIntoView();

    // return when done.
    resolve();
  });
}

const player = new TelemetryPlayer(items, render, 1500);

// now you can do things like speed up etc.


// now you can do things like speed up etc.
function speedUp() {
  // speedup 3 seconds after "playback" starts.
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => {
    player.pause();
    player.interval = 600;
    player.unpause();
    resolve();
  }, 3000));  
}    

function playOnce() {
  // add item once, but not in the array we loop around in
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => {
    player.playOnce(1000);
    resolve();
  }, 3000));  
}
// or add a few items that will be repeated.
function addItems() {
  // add a super very high item 3 seconds after function call.
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => {
    player.pause();
    player.addItem(400);
    player.addItem(430);
    player.addItem(420);
    player.unpause();
    // now rewind to this block. I am off by one, likely.
    player.skipTo(player.items.length - 3);
    resolve();
  }, 5000))
}

speedUp()
.then(playOnce)
.then(addItems);
```